# JavaScript Onclick is not working in tag

Tags: javascript

HTML:

```
<div class="loginDiv">
<form class="validate" role="form">
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <input type="text" id="empId" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <input type="tel" name="mobileNo" maxlength="10" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" required>
    </div>
    <div class="align_center">
        <div class="btn loginBtn" id="regBtn" onclick="new User().register()">REGISTER</div>         
    </div>
</form>
```

Js File

```
var User = function() {    
var self = this;    
self.register = function()     {       
    var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
    var regSeven = /^7[0-9].*$/
    var regEight = /^8[0-9].*$/
    if($("#empId").val() =='')
    {
         alert(Language.InvalidEmployeeId);
         return false;
    }
    if(mobile =='')
    {
         alert(Language.EmptyMobileNumber);
         return false;
    }
}
};
```

if i write a coding for click event like below its working when i use OnClick event function is not calling

```
$("#regBtn").click(function () 
{        
new User().register();   
 })
```

how to make the onclick work.. thanks in advance

Comment: the code should work.Any error you are getting on console?

Comment: you have a missing `"` in onclick.

Comment: you write two function on onclick `new User().register()` in also script

Comment: It's possible that there's no `#regBtn` element in DOM at the moment you call your code. Try `$(document).on('click', '#regBtn', function() { ...stuff... });`

Answer (score 1):

In `onclick` call a function that does `new User().register()`. 
Do not write literal expression, wrap that expression in function and call that function.

Comment: Typos don't need to be answered

Comment: There's no reference to "this" anywhere in the onClick handler. Also using the HTML onclick handler is just ugly in our times.

Comment: @SanchitPatiyal Its kinda too big to be a typo. Maybe you need to check in a dictionary what typo is?

Comment: I agree but he clearly is using it. Not my place to forbid him the usage of something that will work :)

Comment: Even if i use a seperate function for example register() in the onclick event.. the onclick event is not responding

Answer (score 0):

try with this code

```js
$("#regBtn").click(function() {
  var mobile = $("#mobile").val();
  var regSeven = /^7[0-9].*$/;
  var regEight = /^8[0-9].*$/;
  if ($("#empId").val() == '') {
    // alert(Language.InvalidEmployeeId);
    console.log("InvalidEmployeeId");
    return false;
  }
  if (mobile == '') {
    //alert(Language.EmptyMobileNumber);
    console.log("Empty mobile number");
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loginDiv">
  <form class="validate" role="form">
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
      <input type="text" id="empId" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
      <input type="tel" name="mobileNo" maxlength="10" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" onkeyup="javascript:if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" required>
    </div>
    <div class="align_center">
      <div class="btn loginBtn" id="regBtn">REGISTER</div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i want to make use of the onclick event so that function can be reused if i give a id i cant reuse that in another page

Comment: Then you can just use `$(this)` in a handler function as it's called with a button context. You could do it like `var id = $(this).attr('data-id');`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this...

```
<div class="loginDiv">
<form class="validate" role="form">
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <input type="text" id="empId" placeholder="Employee ID" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group float-label-control">
        <input type="tel" name="mobileNo" maxlength="10" id="mobile" placeholder="Mobile Number" onkeyup="if (/\D/g.test(this.value)) this.value = this.value.replace(/\D/g,'')" required>
    </div>
    <div class="align_center">
        <div class="btn loginBtn" id="regBtn" onclick="registerUser()">REGISTER</div>         
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Java script

```
function registerUser(){
   new User().register();
}
```

In this case the function `registerUser()` is re-usable as you commented above `"Actually i want to make use of the onclick event so that function can be reused if i give a id i cant reuse that in another page"`.